# Passando parametro via href php

Tags: php, html

Estou passando um parametro via `href`, porém queria que ficasse oculto o paramêtro na URL.

Estou enviado assim:

```
echo '<a href="edita.php?id=' . $objCont->getid() . '">';
```

Recebo assim no URL:

```
http://.../.../edita.php?id=38779
```

Queria que ficasse assim:

```
http://.../.../edita.php
```

Comment: Não sou da Àrea php, mas de uma olhada nesses 2 links: [Stack Overflow ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459984/php-hide-url-get-parameters) [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit) Adianto aqui que a sugestão é parecida, fazer um form (Dinamico ou não) e usar input's hidden com o parametro na Value do input e usar o metodo post.

Comment: envia como post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Não tem como**, a não ser fazendo uma *bela de uma gambiarra* que no meu ponto de vista é desnecessário, o uso de *querystrings* (`?....`) é justamente este, transportar variáveis via URL para uso de links (URLs), se esta procurando deixar mais bonito a URL realmente acho que esta se preocupando com algo totalmente supérfluo.

As maneira que pode fazer para evitar que URL mude é não fazer o uso de URL, trocar com Ajax, usando talvez um modal, por exemplo com Bootstrap e `<iframe >` (ou [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)) e a outra seria usando POST ou até mesmo URL amigáveis

Um exemplo usando [**Bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo) com o atributo `target=""`:

```css
.modal-body > .editpage {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<a href="edita.php?id=1" target="name" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Editar produto 1
</a>

<a href="edita.php?id=2" target="name" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Editar produto 2
</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe src="about:blank" name="info" class="editpage"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Usando POST

No html ficaria assim:

```
<form method="POST" action="edita.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
    <button>Editar 1</button>
</form>

<form method="POST" action="edita.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
    <button>Editar 2</button>
</form>
```

No php trocaria por isto:

```
<?php

if (empty($_POST['id'])) {
    die('Falta o id');
}

$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Não afeta em nada o uso de POST e GET, mas realmente POST tem uma série de comportamentos que podem fazer estranhar, não estou dizendo que é certo ou errado, mas usar algo apenas para embelezar a URLs é um pouco desnecessário.

### URL amigável

Se usa apache e tiver o modulo rewrite ativado pode usar urls amigáveis também, claro que não melhora em nada, no máximo a leitura, afinal não tem sentido indexar no google páginas de edição

crie um `.htaccess` assim:

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule ^edit/(\d+)$ edita.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Em IIS no `web.config`:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="editar" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^edita/(\d+)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="edita.aspx?id={R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Ou Nginx:

```
location /edit {
    rewrite ^/edit/(\d+)$ /edita.php?id=$1 break;
}
```

Assim ele vai direcionar URLs no formato `http://site/edit/1`, `http://site/edit/2` e `http://site/edit/1001` para `http://site/edit/edita.php?id=1`, `http://site/edit/edita.php?id=1`, etc.

Comment: Outra alternativa para enfeitar as querystrings é a utilização de URL's amigáveis

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não quer botar na resposta também como eu faria com url amigavél ? Para deixar algo assim `http://site/edit/1`

Comment: @Kevin.F pronto editado, adicionei exemplos com Apache (.htaccess), nginx e IIS

Comment: @FelipeNascimento adicionei exemplos com Apache, nginx e IIS para url amigavel, mas pessoalmente penso que é bastante firula para um sistema interno/fechado, de qualquer forma fica para entendimento.

Comment: Então, se eu quiser fazer o contrário ? De `http://site/edit/edita.php?id=1` para `http://site/edit/1` tem como ?

Comment: @Kevin.F como assim o contrário? As urls são assim `http://site/edit/1` sempre com mod-rewrite, o usuário vai ver isto `http://site/edit/1` só o nucleo interno do Apache que vê isto `http://site/edit/edita.php?id=1` ;)

Comment: A ta, viajei. Obrigado.

Comment: Outra coisa, ai no meu no meu `<a>` preciso mudar algo ? Por que não ta funcionando. Continua assim `http://.../.../edita.php?id=38779`.

Comment: @Kevin.F teu servidor é Apache? Não esta funcionando `http://.../.../edit/1` ?

Comment: Isso, é apache, e não está indo assim.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59183/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-kevin-f).

Answer (score -1):

Ao invés de passar o parâmetro por um href, passe-o por uma Session:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $obCont-getId();
header("Location: edita.php");
```

Comment: É que eu preciso passar o `ID` ao clicar em um produto por exemplo. Que na página que recebe este `ID` é editado informações sobre o produto.